# photolibr is preventing my external disk eject

Tags: photos, external-disk

I have my `Photos` library in an external usb3 disk. Usually, `photolibr` prevents the disk from ejecting, even if `Photos` is closed:

```
kukuruzasIII:yoAlcalde_mobile olmo$ lsof | grep DATOS
photolibr  504 olmo   17w     REG                1,7       458  1501411 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/metaSchema.db.lock
photolibr  504 olmo   18u     REG                1,7  29851648  1393588 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/metaSchema.db
photolibr  504 olmo   19u     REG                1,7     16440  1393590 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/metaSchema.db-wal
photolibr  504 olmo   20u     REG                1,7 202260480   793818 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Library.apdb
photolibr  504 olmo   21u     REG                1,7     16440  1393592 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Library.apdb-wal
photolibr  504 olmo   22u     REG                1,7    169984  1393593 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/RKAlbum_name.skindex
photolibr  504 olmo   23u     REG                1,7  16973824   793817 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/ImageProxies.apdb
photolibr  504 olmo   24u     REG                1,7     16440  1393595 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/ImageProxies.apdb-wal
photolibr  504 olmo   25u     REG                1,7  50577408  1393598 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Person.db
photolibr  504 olmo   26u     REG                1,7     16440  1393600 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Person.db-wal
photolibr  504 olmo   27u     REG                1,7 288997376   793819 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Properties.apdb
photolibr  504 olmo   28u     REG                1,7     16440  1393602 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Properties.apdb-wal
photolibr  504 olmo   29u     REG                1,7  13225984  1393603 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/RKVersion_searchIndexText.skindex
photolibr  504 olmo   30r     DIR                1,7       986   790182 /Volumes/DATOS 1/Photos Library.photoslibrary
```

is it safe to just kill `photolibr`? it's not consuming cpu when `Photos` is closed, but the disk is having activity (the lights blinks some times).